# urlparse() query string missing

Tags: python, urlparse

I have two systems:

First one work as intended:

```
>>> urlparse.urlparse('foo://bar/?blu=1')
ParseResult(scheme='foo', netloc='bar', path='/', params='', query='blu=1', fragment='')

# sys.version_info(major=2, minor=7, micro=12, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
```

The second one does it different:

```
>>> urlparse.urlparse('foo://bar/?blu=1')
ParseResult(scheme='foo', netloc='bar', path='/?blu=1', params='', query='', fragment='')

#sys.version_info(major=2, minor=7, micro=3, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
```

What's wrong here?

Both use Python 2.7.

Comment: Can you please include the full Python version? `import sys; print sys.version_info` should give us enough.

Comment: (Python 2.7 has seen a large number of updates and bugfixes over the years, this is almost certainly a version issue).

Comment: Could be related to https://bugs.python.org/issue9374; based on the date that was closed I'd guess it's only in 2.7.7 and up.

Comment: With respect to the [RFC 1808](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1808.html), this is definitely a bug, be sure to check that you have the latest Python 2.7

Comment: I get the first behavior with `2.7.14.final0`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: it was a fix that landed in [2.7.4rc1](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/python/cpython/2.7/Misc/NEWS.d/2.7.4rc1.rst).

Comment: I added the needed version numbers. But one question remains: Whats wrong with this question? Why does it get down-voted?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The second machine is running a very ancient Python 2.7 release. You have run into [issue 9374](https://bugs.python.org/issue9374), a fix for which landed in Python 2.7.4rc1, which [released on 2013-03-23](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/a1f6fab46486ec431c04fe1b0c5c68d6e26f759d), so it's a 2.7 release older than that.

From the [2.7.4rc1 NEWS file](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v2.7.4rc1/Misc/NEWS):

> - Issue #9374: Generic parsing of query and fragment portions of url for any
>     scheme. Supported both by RFC3986 and RFC2396.

The [patch that fixes it](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/6d9c1b1617b30ee24eaa358f4142706148d21922#diff-b577545d73dd0cdb2c337a4c5f89e1d7) is not that big, you could just copy the [fixed `urlsplit()` function](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v2.7.4rc1/Lib/urlparse.py#L167-L220) and monkey patch `urllib` with that if you can't upgrade that machine (you'll have to import some `_private` names from `urllib` first, of course).